# Why does Jadzia Dax wear a science uniform (during the war)?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-uniforms, starfleet-command

During the Federation-Dominion war, we see Jadzia being very engaged in the conflict. She is also taking up new roles, e.g. acting as helmsman of the Jem'Hadar attack ship.

Was she still technically a science officer? Why didn't she wear an operations or command uniform? I get it with Bashir, he still did his primary role as a doctor, but Jadzia did completely different things.

Comment: Why did Worf wear his security/tactical uniform when the Enterprise wasn't in battle? Dax was a science officer. Science officers wear blue.

Comment: Katheryn Janeway was a science officer. She wore red when she became captain of a ship. Why wasn't Dax switched to command when she was given command of the Defiant?

Comment: Data commanded the Enterprise in a gold shirt

Comment: @KevinFee - The Defiant was a remote operating arm / extension of DS9 essentially though - not it's own entirely independent commissioned ship. Ultimately, Sisko is still the CO of the station and by extension of the Defiant and he had delegated the ship to Jadzia during war time operations.

Comment: I'm not talking about short term, i.e. an officer changing uniform if they are acting CO in an emergency. Jadzia was constantly doing war-stuff instead of science-stuff, for months.

Comment: @calina-c I mean, there was a war on...would you prefer Starfleet send a third of its officers off somewhere to take tricorder readings?

Comment: @geewhiz no, but if their tasks changed, they should have changed their uniforms to match the new roles... I'm just guessing.

Comment: @calina-c Their tasks changed temporarily. See my answer below. In fact, during the events of One Little Ship, Dax was doing primarily science officer stuff until the Defiant was attacked.

Comment: its possible that starfleet doesn't have uniform protocols for war. it prides itself on not being a military organisation however changing uniforms specifically to account for a military conflict might not set well with the federations P.R.

Comment: @calina-c Uniform colour is not based on tasks. It is based on division assignment. Science officers tend to do science tasks, it is true, but as geewhiz said there was a war on and both DS9 and Defiant were close to the front lines. I concede that it was a bit weird she didn't get transferred to command for the weeks she commanded the Defiant, after Sisko's "promotion" to being Ross's adjutant (as this didn't seem like a temporary reassignment)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From what we've seen, in universe, Starfleet officers don't change division colors for temporary assignments.

[Worf](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Worf) for example:

> spent most of his first year on the Enterprise-D as a relief officer for the conn and other bridge stations.

When[Tasha Yar was killed](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Skin_of_Evil_(episode)), Worf permanently took over as tactical officer/chief of security and his uniform changed to operations gold. This remained the case until [2372](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Way_of_the_Warrior_(episode)) when he was permanently reassigned to DS9 as strategic operations officer. Despite returning to his tactical role aboard the Enterprise E in all of the TNG era movies, his uniform never changed as those assignments were temporary.

[Geordi La Forge](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Geordi_La_Forge) had a similar experience.

> In 2365, La Forge was promoted to full lieutenant. He transferred from the command division to the operations division and was named chief engineer.

At this point he started wearing operations gold instead of command red.

During the events of [Gambit](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gambit), Data and Worf temporarily commanded the Enterprise in the absence of Picard and Riker. Neither changed their uniform color to command red as it was temporary.

However, [a year earlier](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chain_of_Command%2C_Part_I_(episode)), Riker was relieved of duty and Data was promoted, apparently permanently, to first officer. At that point, he wore command red because the reassignment was meant to be permanent.

[Dax](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jadzia_Dax) was primarily a science officer. Generally, command of the Defiant fell to Worf when Sisko wasn't around but Worf was off serving in the Klingon fleet. Dax was the next highest ranking and most experienced officer available so she was temporarily given command of the Defiant while Sisko was assigned to the Starbase. There was no uniform change because it wasn't a permanent reassignment.

Comment: This is a really good answer! And I know it's a few years old, but I'd like to add my thoughts - In TMP, Kirk stepped down from admiral to captain for what should have been a temporary assignment. He received a change in uniform, and had Captain Decker do the same. He made him take a "temporary grade reduction" from captain to commander, and a change in uniform to show it. And, in 2009's Star Trek, Kirk has Chekov temporarily become Chief Engineering, telling him to "go put on a red shirt". Though I guess this one might have been intended as permanent?